# Nlog + XAMPP logging

Tags: c#, database, logging, xampp, nlog

I have XAMPP installed with a MariaDB database and I would like to collect logs in the database.  Has anyone done it in this configuration before?

```
<target name="database" xsi:type="Database"
    dbProvider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data"
    connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;Database=test;userid=root;password=*****">
```

rules

```
<logger name="app_logger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database" />
```

the logs are not saved in the database and I do not have any notification / error about the lack of connection.  File logs work.

Comment: Maybe post the entire config file? You can also try to enable the internal logger that may reveal any errors with the target: https://blog.elmah.io/nlog-tutorial-the-essential-guide-for-logging-from-csharp/#internal-logging

Comment: hello, thank you for your reply.Internal logger helped - the problem was with the database user who had access to the database only from the localhost level